# Qt WebEngine set socks5 proxy

Tags: qt, pyqt, socks, qtwebengine

I want to set socks5 proxy for my Qt WebEngine app. I use **PyQt5.8 , QT5.8**.

I set up a socks5 server by **danted v1.4.1**. I test my socks5 server and it worked good. But when I use it in my app, **danted** log errors:

> error after reading 3 bytes in 0 seconds: client offered no acceptable authentication method

This is my code:

```
def set_proxy():
    from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkProxy
    proxy = QNetworkProxy()

    from six.moves.urllib import parse as urlparse
    string_proxy = "socks5://username:password@ip:port"
    urlinfo = urlparse.urlparse(string_proxy)
    proxy = QNetworkProxy()
    if urlinfo.scheme == 'socks5':
        proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy)
    else:
        proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.NoProxy)
    if urlinfo.hostname != None:
        proxy.setHostName(urlinfo.hostname)
    if urlinfo.port != None:
        proxy.setPort(urlinfo.port)
    if urlinfo.username != None:
        proxy.setUser(urlinfo.username)
    else:
        proxy.setUser('')
    if urlinfo.password != None:
        proxy.setPassword(urlinfo.password)
    else:
        proxy.setPassword('')
    QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
```

Can anyone help me?

---

### update on 2017/03/29

add **proxyAuthenticationRequired** signal

```
def set_proxy(string_proxy):
    proxy = QNetworkProxy()
    urlinfo = urlparse.urlparse(string_proxy)
    if urlinfo.scheme == 'socks5':
        proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy)
    elif urlinfo.scheme == 'http':
        proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)
    else:
        proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.NoProxy)
    proxy.setHostName(urlinfo.hostname)
    proxy.setPort(urlinfo.port)
    proxy.setUser(urlinfo.username)
    proxy.setPassword(urlinfo.password)
    QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)

def handleProxyAuthReq(url, auth, proxyhost):
    auth.setUser(username)
    auth.setPassword(password)

webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
#proxy_string = "http://username:password@ip:port"
proxy_string = "socks5://username:password@ip:port"
set_proxy(proxy_string)
webView.page().proxyAuthenticationRequired.connect(handleProxyAuthReq)
```

I test it by my **Http proxy** and it worded. But when I use **Socks5 proxy**, the **proxyAuthenticationRequired** signal can not be emited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtWebEngine [does not handle](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtwebengine-overview.html#proxy-support) the username/password information from QNetworkProxy:

> All other proxy settings such as QNetworkProxy::rawHeader(), QNetworkProxy::user(), or QNetworkProxy::password() are ignored.

You'll need to handle [proxyAuthenticationRequired](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qwebenginepage.html#proxyAuthenticationRequired) and handle authentication there.

---

update on 2017/03/30

Looks like [Chromium does not support](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=256785) authentication with SOCKS proxies.

Comment: I have add it to my code. I test it by my Http proxy and it worded. But when I use Socks5 proxy, the proxyAuthenticationRequired signal can not be emited.

Comment: Looks like [Chromium does not support this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=256785).